# jquery widget: attach event to particular element

Tags: jquery, jquery-widgets, jquery-ui-widget-factory

Following is the the snippet of a widget:

```
(function($){
    var ele,_this;
    $.widget('test.mywidget',{
       _loadComments:function(d)
       {
           $.each(d,function(k,v){
            var p=$('<div/>').addClass('comment').attr('id',v.id);           
            p.append("<textarea class='ui-border' onkeypress='_this._submitReply()'></textarea>");
            ele.find('.prevComments').append(p);
           });
       },
       _submitReply:function(){}
       _attachEvent:function()
       {
           ele.on('change','textarea',function(){
              alert('ta pressed');
           });
       }
   _create:function(){
       ele=this.element;
       _this=this;         
       this._loadComments(somedata);          
       this._attachEvent();
   }
});
});
```

The problem is if `this._loadComments(somedata);` has two record and then if i press key inside textarea `alert('ta pressed');` get called 2 times, if it is 10 data it is called 10 times. It should not happens like this. It should call alert message only once for individual textarea.

How can i attach event to individual element? I think here I am attaching event to all textarea that's why.

If i add inline event like `onkeypress='_this._somefunction()'` it says `_this is undefined` but it is there.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y7PbH/1/

Comment: i m not seeing any changes here. Is it just you have pasted my code

Comment: no.. I used `this.element.on('change'`

Comment: here `ele` is the same thing

Answer (score 0):

one option is to remove the event handler each time before you add it.

```
function handleChange(){
  alert('ta pressed');
}


_attachEvent:function()
   {
       ele.off('change','textarea',handleChange);
       ele.on('change','textarea',handleChange);
   }
```